# Work Item Link Types in Visual Studio TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, workitem

What's the difference between the following work items link types in Visual Studio TFS 2010?

- Test Case
- Shared Steps
- Tests
- Tested By

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

"Test Case" and "Shared Steps" are forward name and reverse name for the link type **Microsoft.VSTS.TestCase.SharedStepReferencedBy**. Similarly, "Tested By" and "Tests" are forward name and reverse name for the link type **Microsoft.VSTS.Common.TestedBy**.

Forward name: This is the name with which created link will be known as on the source side.

Reverse Name: This is the name with which created link will be known as on the target side.

For detailed example refer ["TFS 2010: Overview of Workitems linking – Use and Custom Link Type Creation"](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=340)